# Single stepping through shell script

Tags: debugging, shell

Is there an emacs package that would enable single stepping through a shell script, or some facility for setting breakpoints or viewing variables?

Comment: More details, please. How are you invoking the shell script using Emacs? AFAIK, Emacs provides no way to step through a shell script. It just provides ways to edit and invoke shell scripts. You might also want to specify the shell-script language you have in mind.

Comment: As @Drew said, what you probably ask for is likely not supported but if you want to learn more about debugging in Emacs and explore the options you can check out the built-in `debug` package, `dap-mode` (Debug Adapter Protocol) and `realgud` for interacting with external debuggers. For you specific problem you may also find this useful [Debugging Bash scripts](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)